# AUDIO | Brake squeaks when pressing pedal

Tags: brakes, noise, brake-rotor, squeaking

The brakes in my Maxima have been squeaking for a little while whenever I press the pedal. It only happens when going forward, and not in reverse. The car could be parked and when I go into drive and let off the brake pedal, I hear the noise. Here is a link to the noise. It is my rear passenger brake. [Brake noise recording](https://goo.gl/YUQxX1)

Comment: Usually brake noise indicates excessive brake pad wear. Perhaps it’s time to jack up car safely onto jack stands remove rear tires and inspect the outer and inner brake pads (at BOTH top and bottom) for remaining brake pad thickness. I suspect you will find one without remaining pad material.

Comment: @zipzit To me it doesn't sound like it's coming from excessive wear. To you hear the sound byte I attached? The noise is made when pressing and releasing the brake, not while driving fast.

Comment: Sorry. I’m using phone app. No go on listening to that audio on my phone.  And when you jacked up the car and removed the wheels for a close look-see, what did you find?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds to me like a brake pad moving around on the caliper. This typically happens when with excessive or uneven wear, or damaged components. Hard to know for sure just from a recording. The caliper or pads could be rusted and stuck in place.

My advice to you is to inspect the brakes. ***Don't take any chances when it comes to the ability of your vehicle to stop.*** If there are any signs of uneven or excessive wear, do a complete brake job.